# twisted.protocols.basic.LineReceiver only reading one entry (then nothing)

Tags: python, serial-port, twisted, rfid

I'm using the following protocol class to read and parse data coming in from an RFID serial connection. The connection works fine just using pyserial and spitting out what it reads. twisted seems to have an issue reading more than one entry - I'll be able to scan in one of the test accounts and it stops there.

Here's the confusing part - it's not consistent. Sometimes it works as expected, but most times not. What am I doing wrong here?

```
import time, sys

from twisted.internet import reactor, fdesc
from twisted.python import usage, log
from twisted.protocols.basic import LineReceiver
from twisted.internet.serialport import SerialPort
from twisted.web.server import Site
from twisted.web.static import File

from autobahn.websocket import listenWS
from autobahn.wamp import WampServerFactory, WampServerProtocol, exportRpc

test_people = [
    ('8400346926', 'Mary Jones', 'http://placehold.it/150x150&text=Mary+Jones'),
    ('6500129A82', 'Bob Smith', 'http://placehold.it/150x150&text=Bob+Smith'),
]

class ReaderProtocol(LineReceiver):

    t, n, first_pass_time = 0, 0, 0
    first_pass, line, _read_cache, __buffer = None, None, (None, None), ''

    def __init__(self, wsFactory):
        log.msg("Connected to wsfactory %s" % str(wsFactory))
        self.t = time.time()
        self.wsFactory = wsFactory
        self.__buffer = ''

    def connectionMade(self):
        log.msg("Connected to serial port")

    def find_person(self, id):
        for p in test_people:
            if p[0] == id:
                return p

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        stripped_data = data.decode('utf-8').strip()
        if len(stripped_data) == 7:
            self.__buffer = stripped_data
        elif len(stripped_data) == 3 and len(self.__buffer) == 7:
            d = self.__buffer + stripped_data
            self.__buffer = ''
            if len(d) == 10:
                return self.lineReceived(d)
            else:
                log.msg("Incorrect data size. Resetting buffer.")
        else:
            self.__buffer = ''
            log.msg("Incorrect frame size.")
        return

    def lineReceived(self, line):
        i = line.decode('utf-8').strip()
        self.n = time.time()
        if not self.first_pass:
            self.first_pass = i
            self.first_pass_time = time.time()
            self.logLogin(i)
        elif time.time() - self.first_pass_time > 1.5: # make sure past 1.5 seconds
            self.first_pass = i
            self.first_pass_time = time.time()
        else:
            # Make sure that it's not just noise
            if self.first_pass_time > 0 and self.n - self.first_pass_time < 1.5: # not noise
                self.first_pass = None
                self.first_pass_time = 0
                self.logLogin(i)
            else:
                self.__buffer = ''
        return

    def logLogin(self, code):
        f = code != self._read_cache[0] or self._read_cache[1] + 30 <= self.n
        if self.n > self.t + 1.5 and f:
            info = self.find_person(code)
            if info:
                log.msg("ID: %s - Name: %s - Image URL: %s" % (info[0], info[1], info[2]))
                j = "%s|%s|%s" % (info[0], info[1], info[2])
                self.wsFactory.dispatch("http://example.com/serial#login", j)
                self.t = self.n
            else:
                self.wsFactory.dispatch("http://example.com/serial#error", "Unable to find this person.")
            self._read_cache = (code, self.n)
        else:
            pass # this can be safely ignored
        return
```

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone I did reference this post, but setting my data is not an issue. It's not pulling in any data. The data is coming across 8 bits at a time, with the first set in the form "\r[1][2][3][4][5][6][7]". This goes into the buffer. The next read is in the form "[8][9][10]\n". I am checking for both of these and handling them (I think) appropriately.

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone do you have a recommended way that this should be approached?

Comment: Data is not coming across 8 bits at a time.  That's not how stream-oriented transports work.  You subclassed `LineReceiver` and override `dataReceived` which is the exact same mistake as the poster of the other question made (which was explained there already and now I am explaining again, redundantly, here).